# How to ignore Onmouseover in javascript on div with absolute position

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, css-position, onmouseover

I have the following code:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1" style="position: absolute;"></div>
  <div id="div2" onmouseover="not handling"></div>
</body>
```

div1 covers div2. I need to handle `onmouseover` on div2. I assume that div1 handles the `onmouseover` event and postpone it to the body (because the body is a parent element). I cannot change div1 to a "child" of div2. Any ideas?

EDIT: The div1 is semitransparent and has to be always visible and the div2 is filled by color (not transparent). The div2 is also always visible because the div1 is semitransparent. I cannot have div1 inside div2.

Comment: Why do you want to handle the mouseover of an element which won't be shown to the user, but will be hidden by another element?

Comment: because the div1 is semi-transparent

Comment: I have the same issue - in my case it's while I'm dragging an object, so my 'div1' (my drag proxy) is under the mouse and over my 'div2' (the drop zone).  Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The element that is highest in the stacking order (max z-index) will receive the onmouseover event.

To achieve the desired effect, wrap div2 in another div with the highest z-index, give div2 a lower z-index than your overlay.

As div3 has the same bounding box as div2, we attach a onmouseover event to it, and have the event handler act upon div2.

```
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; left:0; top; 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.25; background-color: black;"></div>
    <div id="div3" style="z-index: 20; position: relative;">
    <div id="div2" style="z-index: 0; position: relative;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the z-index because you want div1 to be shown, not behind div2.

Try using pointer-events:none on div1 since u don't want it to affect the onmouseover event.

```
<body>
<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; pointer-events:none"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions to try, not knowing anything about your CSS or page layout:

- Change the Z-index of div2 to be
  higher than div1
- Put div2 first in
  the tag order

Answer (score 0):

By adding a z-index on the divs such that div2's z-index is higher than div1's z-index

e.g.

```
<body>
  <div id="div1" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1"></div>
  <div id="div2" style="position: relative; z-index: 1000" onmouseover="alert('mousemove')"></div>
</body>
```

z-index specifies the stack order of an element (and it can be negative too).

- W3Schools on [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: I can change z-index, but the div1 will hide behind the div2 and that's the problem. :(

Comment: I don't know why you need a div inside a div but why not make div1 background transparent?

Comment: The div1 is semitransparent and has to be always visible and the div2 is filled by color (not transparent). The div2 is also always visible because the div1 is semitransparent. I cannot have div1 inside div2.

Comment: @ChRapO Can you add this last comment to the question body, it changes your question somewhat.

Comment: @andrewjackson, if you can see my post, the link was posted in 2010. Don't you think that it might have changed since? -1 for poor common sense.

Comment: @andrewjackson, the page was moved to another url path. I've updated my post to update the broken link (so, it wasn't taken off their site).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17207/discussion-between-andrewjackson-and-the-elite-gentleman)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you cannot click (or mouseover) **through** a div. So when div1 is 'above' div2 you have a problem.

Isn't it possible to use absolute/relative positioning for both div1 and div2 and use a bigger z-index for div2 than for div1?

Comment: Actually you can, onclick functions exists for divs and it works.